# modify column values other than a specific value is not working

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have below dataframe and need to modify profession column except the value has doctor.

```
id  firstname   lastname    email   profession
0   100 Ekaterina   Skell   Ekaterina.Skell@yopmail.com developer
1   101 Judy    Vernier Judy.Vernier@yopmail.com    police officer
2   102 Tarra   Diann   Tarra.Diann@yopmail.com police officer
3   103 Odessa  Maxi    Odessa.Maxi@yopmail.com firefighter
4   104 Mallory Peonir  Mallory.Peonir@yopmail.com  firefighter
5   105 Nataline    Hoenack Nataline.Hoenack@yopmail.com    doctor
6   106 Dude    Adrienne    Dode.Adrienne@yopmail.com   developer
7   107 Caressa Meli    Caressa.Meli@yopmail.com    doctor
8   108 Zaria   Carey   Zaria.Carey@yopmail.com firefighter
9   109 Harmonia    Seumas  Harmonia.Seumas@yopmail.com worker
```

what i tried is

```
if src[src['profession'].isin(['doctor'])]:
 src['profession'] = src['profession'].astype(str)+'-Done'
```

but i am getting below error.

```
ValueError: The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

How do i get below output(if value has doctor, then it should not append)

```
id  firstname   lastname    email   profession
0   100 Ekaterina   Skell   Ekaterina.Skell@yopmail.com developer-Done
1   101 Judy    Vernier Judy.Vernier@yopmail.com    police officer-Done
2   102 Tarra   Diann   Tarra.Diann@yopmail.com police officer-Done
3   103 Odessa  Maxi    Odessa.Maxi@yopmail.com firefighter-Done
4   104 Mallory Peonir  Mallory.Peonir@yopmail.com  firefighter-Done
5   105 Nataline    Hoenack Nataline.Hoenack@yopmail.com    doctor
6   106 Dude    Adrienne    Dode.Adrienne@yopmail.com   developer-Done
7   107 Caressa Meli    Caressa.Meli@yopmail.com    doctor
8   108 Zaria   Carey   Zaria.Carey@yopmail.com firefighter-Done
9   109 Harmonia    Seumas  Harmonia.Seumas@yopmail.com worker-Done
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) with inverted mask by `~`:

```
#if need compare one scalar value
m = src['profession'].eq('doctor')
#if need compare by list of values
m = src['profession'].isin(['doctor'])

src.loc[~m, 'profession'] = src.loc[~m, 'profession'].astype(str)+'-Done'
```

Or [`numpy.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
src['profession'] = np.where(m, src['profession'], src['profession'].astype(str)+'-Done')
```

If need 100% all strings:

```
s = src['profession'].astype(str)
src['profession'] = np.where(m, s, s+'-Done')
```